# Must supply a value for formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I have `<mat-select  required formControlName="registrationType">`

If I select unregistered two input fields will be disabled, else it will be enabled.
For that I used

```
const registrationType = this.practiceForm.get('registrationType')
    registrationType.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if(value === 'Unregistered'){
            this.form.controls['registrationDate'].disable()
            this.form.controls['registrationNumber'].disable()
          }else if(value === 'registered') {
            this.form.controls['registrationDate'].enable()
            this.form.controls['registrationDate'].enable()
          }
    })
```

The two input fields get disabled as expected when I selected unregistered, but once I click save, the following error: `Must supply a value for form control with name: 'registrationDate'`

The formGroup

```
registrationType: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
registrationDate: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
registrationNumber: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
```

I need help in fixing this. Thank you

Comment: not put `required` in your .html. You indicate is required in the formGroup. As a disabled input not validate, must be work

Comment: @PremKumar please share code on https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 1):

Your validation requires you to have a `required` value in your date.

If you disable fields, the `form.value` doesn't contain the disabled fields.

This means your form is rendered invalid.

To avoid that, remove the validators along with the value :

```
 if(value === 'Unregistered'){
   this.form.controls['registrationDate'].disable()
   this.form.controls['registrationNumber'].disable()
   this.form.controls['registrationDate'].setValidators([])
   this.form.controls['registrationNumber'].setValidators([])
 } else if(value === 'registered') {
   this.form.controls['registrationDate'].enable()
   this.form.controls['registrationDate'].enable()
   this.form.controls['registrationDate'].setValidators([Validators.required])
   this.form.controls['registrationNumber'].setValidators([Validators.required])
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just disable the validators in the code you have like:

```
this.form.controls[""].validator = null;
```

Or you coould use on the form input the disabled attribute:

```
<input [disabled]="some_calculated_property">
```

Should be recognized by angular that's disabled, cause if you manipulate trough code like subscribe to input there won't be standard events that's going to be fired.